# Xcode 5.1 crashing when i try to open .xib file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using xcode 6.1.I have created App using Autolayout. I wanted to test the app on ios6 so I Download the xcode 5.0 when i try to open .xib File xcode is crashing.

Comment: Why do you need that? I think you cannot submit your app from the Xcode 5

Comment: I wanted to test on IOS 6.Client said app is crashing on IOS 6 that the reason .

Comment: Did you set version of your `xib` compatible with Xcode 5?

Comment: now xcode is crashing when I try to open it